# Enable HTTPS self signed cert for GitLab Community Edition for Ominbus installer

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, https, gitlab

I have an Omnibus gitlab installer. I am trying to setup an HTTPS url with self signed cert. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 as my Host OS. The steps im following are:

**Modified gitlab.rb**

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
```

Create Self signed cert with proper name and place it under /etc/gitlab/ssl with permission 600

```
-rw------- 1 root root 1289 Sep 5 08:38 gitlab.example.com.crt
-rw------- 1 root root 1679 Sep 5 08:38 gitlab.example.com.key
```

Then I did gitlab-reconfigure and restart.

So when i try the new URL: `https://gitlab.example.com` the page doesn't load.

The port 443 is open by default and i am able to netcap the same.

I am following this blog for setup - [GitLab HTTPS with selfsigned](http://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Setup_HTTPS_for_Gitlab)

I dont see any errors under /var/log/gitlab

Is there any additional nginx config required for self signed cert?

Can someone please let me know what logs I should be looking for and am i missing any steps.?

Comment: Why not using a valid certificate, from letsencrypt.com for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official documentation is "[Settings NGiNXd](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md)"

Check if [issue 1374](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1374) is relevant in your case.

```
gitlab_rails['registry_key_path'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.example.com.key"
registry['rootcertbundle'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.example.com.crt"
```

> You do not need to specify these two as per documentation on enabling Registry. These two are for internal communication and are auto generated.

Comment: Thanks but that is not an issue in my case

Comment: @Jeel OK. Just in case, double-check the official documentation: it might differ from the blog post you followed.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSL/TLS port is open, the most likely problem is firewall-related.  Check your firewall settings, you may need to run:

```
sudo ufw allow https
```

Answer (score 0):

On recent Gitlab `14.9.2-ce` most `ssl` bugs seemed to be fixed.

- these settings currently work for self signed SSL:

```
# external URL must be https for nginx to also listen on port 443

external_url 'https://gitlab.iac'
letsencrypt['auto_renew'] = false
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80
```

- Also some notes here for having [your browser trust your self signed
  certificate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698783/93470) & how to create them easily.

After running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` you may also need to `gitlab-ctl restart` if `nginx` is not listening on ports `80` & `443` (check with `netstat -lptun`)

If there are still problems if is most likely a firewall issue as already noted here.